# YouTube API v3 Sample IllegalArgumentException, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to simply run the YouTube API v3 in Android Studio, and the app opens fine with a list of buttons that show each functionality, but clicking on any of them crashes the app with this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Developer key cannot be null or empty`. Mind you, this is not my code, but the code from YouTube in their sample folder of their API. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Here is the activity where the "caused by" shows, it says it is at the `DEVELOPER_KEY` line.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.examples.youtubeapidemo;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * A simple YouTube Android API demo application which shows how to create a simple application that
 * displays a YouTube Video in a {@link YouTubePlayerView}.
 * <p>
 * Note, to use a {@link YouTubePlayerView}, your activity must extend {@link YouTubeBaseActivity}.
 */
public class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);

    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
  }

}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.examples.youtubeapidemo, PID: 10226
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.youtubeapidemo/com.examples.youtubeapidemo.PlayerViewDemoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Developer key cannot be null or empty
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2523)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Developer key cannot be null or empty
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ab.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source)
            at com.examples.youtubeapidemo.PlayerViewDemoActivity.onCreate(PlayerViewDemoActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2487)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to follow the steps [YouTube Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup).
check the step-4.

Comment: Ah jeez, that was an easy one. ;) I was actually following that project, but had not read down that far yet. Had so many windows open and so much going on, was more excited to see the app! So it did require my Google API key for my apps... which I already had, so that was easy to put it in to the YouTube java file as required. Thanks!